# Why is latex the standard editor for math/cs journals?

Tags: mathematics, journals, computer-science, presentation, latex

I think latex is a fine language, especially for typesetting math, but sometimes the lack of features for instance making text wrap around an image (\wrapfig can cause issues in places far from where you use it), various commands such as \mathbb not working properly in certain beamer templates etc. images not appearing side by side due to something in a beamer template, working with pocket conflict.. etc

Sometimes it feels like you have to jump through hoops to do/ fix trivial matters?

Better paid editors like overleaf already exist sometimes I wonder how difficult it would be to for microsoft to make a ms latex or something just enough to say  deal with image wrapping, divide up your text so you can find your errors, make flowcharts, image positioning...   better image insertion etc.

I might actually be wrong about this, as I am still a student, but I feel that the latex editor is way more popular than it should be.

Comment: LaTeX itself is not an "editor", but a markup language. There are many choices of "editor" to use to write and debug LaTeX... so somehow the question is misguided...

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer the question in your title, which is specifically about journal articles in math and computer science. In this context, LaTeX is the standard document format for several reasons, including but not limited to:

- It's by far the best widely used format for typesetting math, and unsurprisingly math/CS articles contain a lot of formulas that you'll edit and re-edit during the writing process.
- It lets you focus on content instead of appearance. When you're writing a scientific article, you don't care where exactly the figures go. You'll write e.g. "The process is illustrated in Figure 2" in a proof, and floating somewhere on the same page or the next is Figure 2 with a flowchart. LaTeX does a pretty good job of placing the figure somewhere nearby, all you have to do is import the picture with `\includegraphics` or draw it with e.g. TikZ. Similarly, BibTeX takes care of references so you don't have to format them by hand.
- Journal articles usually need only a small set of popular LaTeX packages that are well maintained and don't conflict with each other. Many journals explicitly ask you to not use "exotic" packages that may cause trouble during their typesetting process.
- LaTeX source files are just text files. This makes collaborative editing and version control much simpler than with dedicated formats like Word. You don't have to worry about losing all formatting if your colleague has a different version of Word or uses an Apple or Linux system. Any text editor can handle `.tex` files, from Notepad to dedicated programs like TeXworks or the web-based Overleaf.
- Historical inertia: LaTeX is the standard because it's been the standard for years. Most journals require or heavily encourage it and basically everyone knows how to use it. People don't like change if the current situation works well enough.

Beamer is kind of a special case since it changes the layout of your document so fundamentally and doesn't play well with many other packages. If you're making a presentation with special fonts and lots of figures that need to be placed exactly right, maybe Beamer is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: *Journal articles usually need only a small set of popular LaTeX packages that are well maintained and don't conflict with each other.* Yes, but journal styles are actually the biggest offenders here. They are often quirky and outdated.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're right, most of them have their own weird preface format and seem to conflict with amsthm specifically.

Answer (score 4):

You use whatever tool you need for the occasion. In the case of LaTeX, its main competitor is Microsoft Word. Now it's not like Word is a bad editor - in fact for simple things I'd say Word is outright better - but when it comes to rendering equations LaTeX does things much better than Word.

For example say you want to type the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Statement) (the one in the green box as of time of writing) in Word. How would you do it? You could insert -> equation and start filling in the symbols, but it'll be a pain to find the symbols for partial derivatives, and what's more after you find it you'll have to manually reinsert it again each time. Comparatively in LaTeX you can just write \partial and you'll get it. This neglects the fact that some of the terms in the equation has an over-dot, and again that will be difficult to add in Word while it's [fairly simple in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44017/dot-notation-for-derivative-of-a-vector).

Ultimately you use whatever tool you need for the occasion, but if you're writing heavy mathematical texts (and math/CS journals certainly use a lot of math), TeX is usually superior.